# Copy transitive dependecies from pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to copy the dependencies of my pom file in a specific directory. But one of the dependency is as packaging type "pom" and i want to copy the dependencies of the this pom also in the specific directory. 
I'm using the maven-dependency plugin to copy the dependencies.

My project pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
   <groupId>org.company</groupId>
   <artifactId>any-artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.company</groupId>
         <artifactId>other-artifact</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                     <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                     <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                     <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

The pom of the other-artifact looks f.ex. like this:

```
<project>
    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>other-artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>module-one</module>
        <module>module-two</module>
    </modules>
        <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

How can i reach, that i can copy also the dependencies from the pom file.

Comment: That should work. Can you post a simple [mcve]? What coordinates are you using?

Comment: Coordinates of what? You can see the dependencies tag, i replaced the coordinates with variables..

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the real coordinates, because this should work so there is something wrong somewhere else. Did you `clean` before? Like I commented before, please make a [mcve].

Comment: Try using <scope>import</scope> for the dependency you are including.

Comment: @Tunaki is this enough for you, that you can answer?

Comment: Ha, that is because you're dependencies are inside `dependencyManagement` section. So you need to move your `other-artifact` of type `pom` dependency to a `dependencyManagement` section of `any-artifact` and add `<scope>import</scope>`.

Comment: I move d the `dependencies` section in the `dependencyManagement` tag and added the `<scope>import</scope>` in the dependency of `other-artifact`, BUT it doens't copy the dependencies of the pom.xml from other-artifacts in the `/lib` directory, there is only the pom file of `other-artifact`

Comment: Sorry, my comment above is incorrect. The issue is that your `other-artifact` does not depend on `guava` or `slf4j-api`, it only lists them in the `dependencyManagement`. So they won't be included, and I don't think you can't fix that at `any-artifact`'s level, who is depending on that. You need to add an explicit `<dependency>` section in your `other-artifact` POM on both `guava` or `slf4j-api` if you somehow want to include them.

Comment: But there are a lot of submodules of `other-artifact`.. I never can expand the pom file manually... There should be a possibility...